# vim Vundle's PluginInstall conflict with fish in Archlinux

Tags: vim, zsh, archlinux, fish, vundle

In Arch, when I use Vim Vundle's PluginInstall/PluginUpdate, it will show many mistake message

```
Processing 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>146_process..vundle#installer#run..vundle#installer#ins
tall..<SNR>146_sync..<SNR>146_make_sync_command..<SNR>146_get_current_origin_url..<SNR>146_system:
line    1:
E484: Can't open file /tmp/v8J8IUB/7
Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>146_process..vundle#installer#run..vundle#installer#ins
tall..<SNR>146_sync:
line    6:
E714: List required
Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>146_process:
line   13:
E121: Undefined variable: s:last_status
E15: Invalid expression: 'error' == s:last_status
line   17:
E121: Undefined variable: s:last_status
-- More --
```

I have to type `Enter` repeatly so that it can `process` next Plugin, and while processing every plugin, it will show the same mistake message:

```
Processing 'sjl/gundo.vim'
Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>146_process..vundle#installer#run..vundle#installer#ins
tall..<SNR>146_sync..<SNR>146_make_sync_command..<SNR>146_get_current_origin_url..<SNR>146_system:
line    1:
E484: Can't open file /tmp/v8J8IUB/12
Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>146_process..vundle#installer#run..vundle#installer#ins
tall..<SNR>146_sync:
line    6:
E714: List required
Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new..<SNR>146_process:
line   13:
E121: Undefined variable: s:last_status
E15: Invalid expression: 'error' == s:last_status
line   17:
E121: Undefined variable: s:last_status
```

When I set `fish` shell as default shell , it will conflict. when I switch back to `zsh`, it will work normally. How can I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either update to at least Vim 7.4.276, which [adds support for fish](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.4/7.4.276), or set the shell that Vim uses to one that your version of Vim supports (like zsh):

```
set shell=/usr/bin/zsh
```